# Google App Script for loop anda Utilities.sleep problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my code snippet working:

```
function loadBusinessProposalData () {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSS).getSheetByName("dctPro");
  var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSS).getSheetByName("Gerar");
  var source = sourceSheet.getRange(2,3,1,sourceSheet.getLastColumn() - 2);
  const valuesToPaste = source.getValues();

  generateReferenceCellMap();

  for (let i = 0; i < valuesToPaste[0].length; i++) {
      var destination = pasteSheet.setActiveSelection(referenceCells[i]);
      destination.setValue(valuesToPaste[0][i]);
      //if (i = 129) {
      //  console.log(i); //for test
      //  Utilities.sleep(1500);
      //}
  }

function generateReferenceCellMap () {
  var referenceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSS).getSheetByName("dcPro");
  var referenceRange = referenceSheet.getRange(2,3,1, referenceSheet.getLastColumn() - 2);
  var referenceFormulas = referenceRange.getFormulas();

  for (let i = 0; i < referenceFormulas[0].length; i++) {
    var reference = getCellReferenceByFormulaReference(referenceFormulas[0][i]);
    referenceCells.push(reference);
  }
}

function getCellReferenceByFormulaReference(formulaReference) {
  
  var delimiterSheetPosition = formulaReference.indexOf("!");
  var cellReference = formulaReference.slice(delimiterSheetPosition + 1);

  return cellReference;
  //console.log(cellReference);
}
```

But I need to force a wait in the middle of the for loop for a formula to update in the worksheet, so I can continue the for loop and change the other cells.

I already tried this way:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < valuesToPaste[0].length; i++) {
      var destination = pasteSheet.setActiveSelection(referenceCells[i]);
      destination.setValue(valuesToPaste[0][i]);
      if (i = 129) {
        console.log(i); //for test
        Utilities.sleep(1500);
      }
  }
```

Thus:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < valuesToPaste[0].length; i++) {
      var destination = pasteSheet.setActiveSelection(referenceCells[i]);
      destination.setValue(valuesToPaste[0][i]);
      if (i = 129) {
        console.log(i); //for test
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
  }
```

And thus:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < valuesToPaste[0].length; i++) {
      var destination = pasteSheet.setActiveSelection(referenceCells[i]);
      destination.setValue(valuesToPaste[0][i]);
      if (i = 129) {
        console.log(i); //for test
        Utilities.sleep(1500);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
  }
```

But in all ways apparently the variable i stops being incremented, and the script loops

Could you help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Please zoom out a little and explain what you are doing because it looks like you may be over complicating the process.

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and also a [mcve]

Comment: I put the beginning of the code.
Thanks.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `if (i = 129)` should be this `if (i == 129)` or possibly this `if (i === 129)`

Comment: Primary error.
It was just that.
Sorry for the inattention. I'm starting now with the scripts.
Thanks.
Code that solved the problem: 
`for (let i = 0; i < valuesToPaste[0].length; i++) {
      var destination = pasteSheet.setActiveSelection(referenceCells[i]);
      destination.setValue(valuesToPaste[0][i]);
      if (i == 129) {
        console.log(i); //for test
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
  }`

Comment: I don't read code in comments